# Do I need dedicated linux user for scheduled tasks?

Tags: linux, bash, security, crontab

Say I have bash scripts for backup/sync/download from internet/update tasks. I'm going to run them on schedule with crontab. Is it safe to create crontab for root, or do I need dedicated linux user? And, if I need it, why do I?

UPD: Actually there are three options:
1) root - Ok. It's bad option.
2) existing user.
3) dedicated user.

Is dedicated user any better than exising(e.g. workstation owner, regular user)?
Given that I can't make dedicated user nologin, because I'm using rsync over ssh and I will have to add new user on remote machine with which I'm syncing.

Comment: Just to mention one security threat, if you DNS is somehow compromised, then you would download a potentially threatening script. You would be so happy that you did not use root. Also, consider using `/bin/false` as shell for that user.

Comment: Yes. I've made a user nologin on computer that runs cronjob. And I'm going to change user's login shell to restricted on remote server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's **always** better to run things as a non-root user with exactly as much access and permissions as it needs, and nothing more.

Whether it is "safe" to run something as root depends on what it does (*echo "" > /dev/null* seems relatively harmless :) ), but it is **always** less safe than running it as a non-root user, because you never know what eventuality you may be overlooking where something may affect something it shouldn't be affecting.

Here's something that happened to me once, just as an example: what if you accidentally write a dangerous bash command into the script file by a copypaste fail where you copied part of your bash history into the script (that for instance contains some *rm -rf* command on a relative path, instead of the lines from the superuser post with the example code). Was I happy that I ran that cronjob under the correct user :) Now all that happened was that that user's git config was lost...

Comment: Hi, SadBunny. Yes, I had this too: exhaled in relief few times when saw:`can't remove .. permission denied` in my case that mostly were wrong filters for rm command. But I want to consider another option: running as existing user, as I have this dilemma for workstation automation. Could you check updated question?

Comment: Well, the same things apply more or less, dedicated user is of course safer because what if you forget about the cronjob 6 months down the line when you change something in the existing user, maybe temporarily give it more rights, change ssh keys, or maybe remove it altogether... The risk is certainly less than using root, of course, so if those are your options and you feel a dedicated user requires you to bend over backwards too far, then sure. I could see myself make that compromise, although I wouldn't tell anyone :)